# Aligment in stack view

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uistackview

I'm using UIStackViews with UILabels in my project. Basically I have horizontal stack view and two labels inside. Alignment: Fill, Distribution: Fill proportionally. I'd expect that second label will be right after first one. But it's not.I tried various alignments but nothing worked. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**iPhone screenshot:**
[image]

**xib file:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You screenshot doesn't show the constraints your using in your xib but I assume there is a constraint stating that the right/trailing side of your `UIStackView` should equal the right/trailing side of your view. If you change it so the `UIStackView` is <= your view, it should layout how you want.

Comment: Today is Xcode so buggy that I stopped think. Than you!